# Mock server with Java Code for handling custom logic

Tags: karate

I have perfectly running Mock API server based on Karate.  There is some custom Java code that I also want to execute when Scenario is matched.

Executing the Mock using jar as follows

```
java -jar karate-0.9.0.jar -m ./src/test/java/Mymock.feature -p 9000
```

Mymock.feature has something like follows

```
  Scenario: pathMatches('/')
    * def Signature = Java.type('Signature')
    * def sign = Signature.calculate('382700b563f4', {'userId':'399645532', 'os':'android', 'client_key':'3c2cd3f3', 'token':'141a649988c946ae9b5356049c316c5d-838424771', 'token_client_salt':'d340a54c43d5642e21289f7ede858995'})
    * print sign.sig
    * print sign.__NStokensig
```

Code above works fine when executed directly via a Feature file.

But As expected this gives error if its invoked if embedded in Mocks.

```
Mymock.feature:70 - javascript evaluation failed: Java.type('Signature'), java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Signature
```

How can I execute Java code embedded in mocks?
I am not dependent on jar to execute Mocks so can easily try new way to execute Java Code in Mocks though any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Java I suggest you start the mock server via the Java API (embedding). This is what most teams do: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#embedding

And what happens then is the classpath will automatically include all the stuff you need, such as `Signature`.

But with a little effort you should be able to do what you want. What is happening is `Signature` is not on the `classpath`. Since you know Java, what you should do is **a)** make `Signature` available as a compiled `*.class` file or `*.jar` file somewhere, and then **b)** add it to the Java classpath.

EDIT: refer to this other post for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458094/143475

Comment: Not able to do it with `java -cp some/folder -jar karate-0.9.0.jar` 
Will create a sample for this on github, Also will add example to start multiple mocks in there.

using JAVA API I was able to at least start it for now.

Comment: I am still working on providing a sample for using Mock, please give me sometime on it.

Comment: @AmitVyas update - refer this for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458094/143475