# How do I pass gitlab-ci variables to karate Netty jar?

Tags: gitlab-ci, karate

I'm trying to use Karate Netty jar in a gitlab-ci pipeline.  I'm pulling in an image that contains the jar as a step in the pipeline.  I am able to execute tests just fine for unsecured services.
Like so:

```
karate-test:
    stage: acceptance-test
    image:
        name: registry.gitlab.opr.business.org/karate-universe:0.0.3
        entrypoint: [ "" ]
    script:
        - java -jar /karate.jar -e dev src/test/karate/acceptance-test.feature -o /target/karate
    environment:
        name: Test
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - /target/karate
```

Now I'm trying to pass credentials into a karate feature for a secured service but cannot find the capabilities from the jar interface.

I've tried passing the credentials like so:

```
    - java -jar /karate.jar -e dev src/test/karate/acceptance-test.feature -o /target/karate -Duser.password ${REQUEST_PASSWORD} -Duser.id ${REQUEST_USER}
```

REQUEST_PASSWORD and REQUEST_USER are gitlab variables that are available to me in gitlab-ci.

When I run the pipeline, I get:

```
Unmatched arguments [-Duser.password, -Duser.id]
```

Does Karate Netty have the capabilities of being able to pass variables for karate-config use like regular Karate does?  I cannot keep secrets in the karate-config file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `-Dfoo=bar` part comes *before* the `-jar` option, because everything after that is passed to Karate, and *not* the JVM.

```
java -Dfoo=bar -Dbaz=ban -jar /karate.jar
```

Note that you can also get [environment variables easily](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/547#issuecomment-427017681):

```
java.lang.System.getenv('PATH')
```

Normally people pass values as `-D` JVM options. If you have some advanced needs for the standalone JAR - see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458094/143475

Comment: I was already using the -D variables, but this got me on the right track!
I was putting them at the end instead of before the -jar switch.

Comment: I forget the javascript is running in a JVM...  Counterintuitive for me to grab environment variables using javascript, but I'm glad its so simple!

Comment: I actually used karate.properties['userId'] instead of java.lang.System.getenv.  Couldn't seem to get that to work.