# How to read variables in karate-config.js from Java

Tags: karate

In karate-config.js I set the baseUrl based on an environment. I want to be able to get this url in Java so I can get the corresponding server name in the url. Please show me how to do this. My karate-config.js looks something like this:

```
  if (env == 'test') {
      var baseUrl = 'http://server1:8080/api';
  } else if (env == 'dev') {
      var baseUrl = 'http://server2:8080/api';
  }
```

I wrote a Java utility to connect to the database and run a query. But I need to know if the database is on server1 or server2 as in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `baseUrl` is added to the JSON returned by `karate-config.js`:

There is nothing special. `baseUrl` can be used "as-is" and passed as a method argument if you call any Java code. For example:

```
* def MyUtil = Java.type('com.myco.MyUtil')
* def result = MyUtil.doSomeWork(baseUrl)
```

Please read the docs for more: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

Comment: I think my question is not clear. Supposed my dbUtils have a method called runQuery that executes a query and returns the results. In my feature file I have something like this:
`
    * def myUtil = Java.type('dbUtils')
    * def results = myUtil.runQuery(query)
`
In the method runQuery I want to get the server name in the baseUrl so I can connect to the database on that server. I actually need to open a config file on that server and read the database connection information in the config file. So the connection may be different depending on what server I'm running the tests on.

Comment: No, Sir.  I already wrote the method and it works. But I'm hard coding the server name right now.  When I run on a different server, I have to change the name.  I'm trying to read the server name dynamically.

Comment: I found a workaround for now which is getting the server name from within the feature file and pass it back to Java.

Comment: @bhc that is not a workaround. that is the solution. if you are getting the server name from a variable. and if the variable is coming from `karate-config.js`. is this so hard to understand ? I want to know so that I can fix the documentation

Comment: The documentation is fine. I just don't want to have to modify many of my feature files. I prefer to change only the method so the feature files still work. I'm going to try to see if I can set an environment variable in karate-config.js then I can get it in Java.

Comment: @bhc is that all you need ? to use the environment. yes your question is terrible, for example look at the question title itself - it talks about variables. please be more clear next time. and read this, it will answer all your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57261852/143475

Comment: My initial thought was the variable "baseUrl" in karate-config has what I need. So it would solve my problem if I could get it. But now I found out I could not get it. So I thought of another way which is to use an environment variable. Thank you for the link. I know how to get an environment variable in Java but not how to set it in JavaScript or Java. I may not be easy or possible.

Comment: @bhc for **you** it may not be easy or possible ! all the best :)

Comment: I decided to use System.setProperty and System.getProperty. That worked well for me. Thanks.

Comment: @bhc there are better ways. but I guess reading the documentation is too hard