# Managing Secrets in Karate

Tags: karate

I am looking for a way to manage: (keep, use, update) secrets in Karate framework.
In my Python and node frameworks I have been using `.env` file for that task + some classes/methods to retrieve the secrets from a secure place, update the `.env` file etc.

What's the best way to do this in Karate?

These are the requirements:

1. User should be able to use CLI to provide the secrets
2. If no secrets provided, a default value should be used
3. Values are different based on the env

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `karate-config.js` is to manage all config variables dynamically. Refer to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#switching-the-environment

If you have secrets that you don't want checked into source control, you can suck them in from the CLI or System environment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57261852/143475

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I don't want to to check any of the secrets into source control , neither the company's policy would allow that.