# Scenario Outline And Examples in karate

Tags: karate

I want to run my scenario with all the images that i have in my resource folder. meaning every time hitting same api with different image(converting them to base64encoding first) .But as this images already are in resource folder than it does not make sense to save with some name or records in csv for scenario outline purpose. Can i call a my own function (having code to take the image from resource folder and convert it into base64) in Examples section , So that for every image it will hits the same api again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First write some java code to get a list of the image files. You can refer this code for ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65035825/143475

If that is too hard, then just create a CSV file with a list of paths. Let me say that Karate is designed for testing, but you seem to be expecting something else. Karate is not a "general purpose" programming language. But it can be made to do extreme things by [Java interop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java).

One you have a JSON array, then it can be used as the data-source for the `Examples:` section: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-array-data-source

You can refer other answers for Base64 conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452864/143475

All the things you want to do is possible, but please do some research and try. And the next time you ask a question, please show what you tried and give examples instead of just a broad question, thanks.