# How to assert if sikuli image is present or not using Karate Feature file in UI Automation?

Tags: java, testing, ui-automation, karate, assertion

How to assert if sikuli image is present or not using Karate Feature file in UI Automation?
assert exists(imagepath) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Karate UI has no such feature. You can see if [Karate Robot](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot) works for you.

Also note that you can integrate Sikuli, but it needs some research: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458094/143475