# I want to run karate as a stand-alone executabl (or jar) and I want to configure a logModifier. How can I do that?

Tags: java, karate

I downloaded Karate as a [stand alone executable](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release), and it's working well.

I want to mask sensitive headers in the 'log' output.  I gather that the way to do that is via [configuring a logModifier](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#log-masking).

But, I can't figure out to make it effective.

I tried the following:

1. put this snippet in my `karate-config.js` :

```
  var LM = Java.type('demo.headers.DemoLogModifier');
  karate.configure('logModifier', LM.INSTANCE);
```

2. in the root of where the karate stand-alone binary exists, i made the directory src/demo/headers/, and then put my DemoLogModifier.java in that dir.  I also tried putting the .java in a different tree: src/test/java/demo/headers.  I also tried putting in that same directory hierarchy at the root of where my *.feature files are.  In every case, karate fails every Scenario, saying "TypeError: Access to host class demo.headers.DemoLogModifier is not allowed or does not exist".

Is this possible to do with the stand alone executable?  If so, how?

If not, how then?  I'm a java newbie, and i can't tell from [the documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate) how to make my own stand-alone jar *and* include my custom DemoLogModifier.java class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you need to use a `LogModifier`, it requires you to build Java code.

Can you refer to this answer, it should get you on your way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458094/143475

The good thing is that the Java side is a one-time effort, so do consider getting the help of someone else just for that part. Then you will be up and running.

Feel free to submit a feature request for making this easier for the standalone JAR in the future.